# Dialog with ListView does not return proper ID

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a dialog that shows a `ListView` of certain items like this

```
d = new Dialog(this);
d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
d.setTitle("Select Bowler " + String.valueOf(bakerList.size()+1));

ListView lv3 = (ListView)d.findViewById(R.id.dialog_list);
Cursor c3 = getContentResolver().query(TeamBowlers.CONTENT_URI,new String[] {TeamBowlers.ID,TeamBowlers.SUB,TeamBowlers.BOWLER_ID,TeamBowlers.CAPTAIN}
    ,TeamBowlers.TEAM_ID + "=?",new String[] {String.valueOf(teamSelectedID)},TeamBowlers.POSITION + " ASC");                                       

if(c3.moveToFirst() && c3 != null){
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2 = new ImageAdapter(this,R.layout.row,c3
            ,new String[] {TeamBowlers.ID,TeamBowlers.SUB,TeamBowlers.BOWLER_ID},new int[] {R.id.icon,R.id.bowler_txt,R.id.bowler_txt2});

    lv3.setAdapter(adapter2);
    lv3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long id) {
            bakerList.add(id);
            updateName(id);
        }

    });
    d.show();
}
```

problem is that when I click on an item in the list the ID that gets returned is not the id from the database it just returns the index basically.

why is it not binding my "_id" column of my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
why is it not binding my "_id" column of my database?
```

I guess it is not true. That `id` in the `onItemClick` is actually the `row id` in list view, it is not the `id` from your `cursor`

If you want the row data you can do some thing like this in `onItemClick`

```
Cursor cursor = ((SimpleCursorAdapter) arg0).getCursor();
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
long _id= cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
```

Comment: This ended up not being my problem, but I did also end up returning the the correct id so good to know this works too